# How can I join multiple tables?

Tags: sql, join

I have a database with a table that looks like this. I need a query that will output both the address name of the worker and the work location.

**Tables**

[image]

**The output should look like this.**
[image: Output]

Here is the query I'm trying to use.

```
SELECT workers.first_name, workers.last_name, workers.address_code, lib_address.address_name AS personal_address, work_details.address_code, work_details.work_type, lib_address.address_name AS work_address
FROM workers
JOIN work_details ON workers.work_code=work_details.work_code
JOIN lib_address ON work_details.address_code=lib_address.address_code;
```

Comment: what havve you tried

Comment: 1) Do not use pictures, provide code-formatted textual CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO instead. 2) Do not post facts as comments, add them into the question marking them as an update.

Answer (score 1):

You must use 2 copies for address table.

`address_code` in `workers` and in `work_details` are not dependent and needs in independent `lib_address` copies to be joined.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM workers w
JOIN lib_address la_1 ON w.address_code = la_1.address_code
JOIN work_details wd ON w.work_code = wd.work_code 
JOIN lib_address la_2 ON wd.address_code = la_2.address_code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select w1.first_name,
w1.last_name,
w1.address_code,
l1.address_name as Personal_address,
l1.address_code,
w2.work_type,
w2.work_address from workers w1,lib_address l1,work_details w2
where w1.address_code = l1.address_code
and l1.address_code = w1.address_code
order by first_name;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).